# OpenAM SSO SAML AuthnRequestsSigned error

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, nestjs, openam

I am trying to set the *signing and encryption* option on my SP metadata to have `AuthnRequestsSigned="true"` but my AM server keeps throwing the below Error in the /debug/Federation log

*Authentication Requests Signed* option is the only one giving me issues.

Im running

> ForgeRock Access Management 6.5.2
>   Tomcat 8.0.35
>   openjdk version "1.8.0_212"

**AM Settings**

[image]

**Error Message**

```
libSAML2:08/02/2019 03:16:50:299 PM UTC: Thread[http-nio-80-exec-8,5,main]: TransactionId[f1638b0a-6687-4953-ae04-8ce8c9299079-62363]
ERROR: UtilProxySAMLAuthenticator.authenticate: authn request destination verification failed for
IdpEntity: http://x.canadacentral.cloudapp.azure.com:80/opensso
MetaAlias: /idp Destination: http://x.canadacentral.cloudapp.azure.com/opensso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp
Location: http://x.canadacentral.cloudapp.azure.com:80/opensso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp
```

**SP Meta-data**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" validUntil="2019-08-02T12:04:36Z"
                     cacheDuration="PT604800S" entityID="nestjs-sp-signed-0070">   

    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="true"
                        protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>...
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>...
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>

        <md:NameIDFormat>
            urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
        </md:NameIDFormat>

        <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                                Location="http://localhost:3000/auth/logout/callback"/>

        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                                     Location="http://localhost:3000/auth/login/callback" index="0"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post"
                                     Location="http://localhost:3000/auth/login/callback" index="1"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"
                                     Location="http://localhost:3000/auth/login/callback" index="2"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01"
                                     Location="http://localhost:3000/auth/login/callback" index="3"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:profiles:holder-of-key:SSO:browser"
                                     Location="http://localhost:3000/auth/login/callback" index="4"/>
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>

</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

**Passport Settings**

```js
export const samlPassportConf = {
    issuer: 'nestjs-sp-signed-0070', // match metadata entityID

    identifierFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',

    callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/login/callback',
    entryPoint: 'http://x.canadacentral.cloudapp.azure.com/opensso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp',
    logoutUrl: 'http://x.canadacentral.cloudapp.azure.com/opensso/IDPSloRedirect/metaAlias/idp',

    privateCert: fs.readFileSync('cert/privatekey.pem', 'utf-8'),
    decryptionPvk: fs.readFileSync('cert/privatekey.pem', 'utf-8'),
};
```

Comment: https://forum.forgerock.com/topic/saml-destination-verification-failed/

Comment: i cant figure out what the solution is in that topic

Comment: The target URL in your SAML authentication request (`Destination` element) doesn't match the configuration of the service provider in your IdP.

Comment: Here is what i dont get, i unchecked _authentication requests signed_ and it works. i check it and it doesn't. So should the destination change if i check _authentication requests signed_.

Comment: When it's checked, additional constraints (beyond validating the signature) are enforced

Comment: I understand the problem but I cant figure out how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

**Question**:

I am trying to set the signing and encryption option on my SP metadata to have AuthnRequestsSigned="true" but my AM server keeps throwing the below Error in the /debug/Federation log

(1) Authentication Requests Signed option is the only one giving me issues.

(2) I unchecked authentication requests signed and it works.

**Answer**:

(1) You unchecked authentication requests signed, indicating that OpenAM SAML IdP would never verify the signature of authentication request sent by your SAML SP, thus it works as you expected.

(2) Your SAML SP signs Authentication Request using a signing key.

OpenAM SAML IdP uses the corresponding public cert (which it extracts from your SAML SP metadata) to verify the signed Authentication Request sent by your SAML SP.

If the Authentication Request is signed, OpenAM SAML IdP MUST verify Destination (i.e., SAML Login URL/Entrypoint of SAML IdP) and entityID of SAML SP.

Two issues have been identified:

(I) Destination "http://x.canadacentral.cloudapp.azure.com/opensso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp"

does NOT exactly matches the location/entryPoint

"http://idp5.canadacentral.cloudapp.azure.com/opensso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp"

Your SAML SP sends "idp5.canadacentral", but OpenAM SAML IdP receives "x.canadacentral"

(II) issuer: 'nestjs-sp-signed-0070' in the Authentication Request sent by your SAML SP

does NOT match

entityID="nestjs-sp-signed-0090"
in your SAMP SP metadata uploaded to OpenAM SAML IdP.

**Resolution**:
In your Passport Settings, Replace 'nestjs-sp-signed-0070' with 'nestjs-sp-signed-0090', because OpenAM SAML IdP MUST verify that entityID of your SAML SP 'nestjs-sp-signed-0070' carried by the Authentication Request should be exactly equal to entityID of your SAML SP 'nestjs-sp-signed-0090' in your SAML SP metadata.

(III) You need to ensure that private key and public cert should be a key pair. that is,

private key "privateCert: fs.readFileSync('cert/privatekey.pem', 'utf-8')" in your Passport Settings

should be corresponding to

public cert in your SAML SP metadata

```
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>...
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
```

**Potential root cause** of Authentication Requests Signed is that 
OpenAM SAML IdP uses the public cert of encryption (carried by your SAML SP metadata) to verify the signed Authentication Request. That is, OpenAM SAML IdP uses the wrong public cert for signature verification.

**Resolution**:

Use the same key pair for both signing and encryption. In your SAML SP metadata, let both signing cert and encryption cert "" be the same, that is,

```
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>...
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
```

is the same as

```
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>...
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
```